# Yandex.касса и Android SDK

Tags: php, android, яндекс-касса

Имеет место быть некий сайт с платными услугами. Онлайн реализованы отношения с кассой через API. Все работает гуд. Однако заказчик пожелал еще и мобильное приложение для оказания тех же услуг. Что имеем: разрабы с помощью SDK получают токен и передают на back. я пытаюсь создать платеж

```
 $payment = $client->createPayment(                                                     
    array('payment_token'=>$contents->payment), uniqid('', true));
```

где `$contents->payment` это токен с клиента.
В ответ получаю: 
`pt-27--------395d{"error":"Failed to build request \"YandexCheckout\\Request\\Payments\\CreatePaymentRequest\": \"Invalid payment amount value: 0.00\""}`

Что не так делаю я или что не так с токеном?

Answer (score 1):

```
$payment = $client->createPayment([
  'amount' => [
    'value' => '99.00',
    'currency' => 'RUB',
  ],
  'payment_token' => $contents->payment,
], uniqid('', true));
```

Поле amount (сумма) является обязательным

Comment: действительно, required. Но если указать amount получаем другую ошибку {"error":"Error in the payment token. Specify a valid token from our client library.Error code: invalid_request.Parameter name: payment_token."}. Где руки выпрямить?

Comment: @pincet, может быть, токен неправильно генерируется в приложении или неправильно парсится из полученных от приложения данных

Comment: парсится норм, ибо в ответ высылаю его же. а вот за валидность токена - буду кошмарить разрабов приложения, ибо техподдержка  предполагает, что токенизируется некая "тестовая" карта, а платеж подкидывается в продуктив